# PHP - mysqli function

Tags: php, mysqli

At the moment I use the `mysql_connect`, `mysql_select_db`, `mysql_query` functions from PHP. I have a file with `mysql_connect` so I can require this file in all other PHP files and I have in every file a connection to MySQL.

Now i have to change it to `mysqli_connect`. The problem now: I have for all query to set a connection? why? after one query the Connection will be closed. So I have to set a new `mysqli_connection`.

Is this ok, or what do I have to do that I need only one connection?

Connection.php

```
  $connect = mysqli_connect("test","test","test","test");
```

other php-file:

```
require("./Connection.php");

$result= mysqli_query($connect,"select portfolioview_id,portfolioview_text,portfolioview_longtext from portfolioview order by portfolioview_id desc");
while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($connect,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    echo "test";                            

endwhile;
```

After this query, so when i start an second query i get the message:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\limitless\connect_to_mysql.php on line 17

When i add a new Connection like in Connection.php it works.

Comment: `$mysqli =  mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","dbname");` save it as `connect.php`

Comment: As long as you dont close the connection (and you won't have a reason to close it, if you used one connection before) you can reuse it.

Comment: i tried it to save it in "connect.php". i works only once. after i set a new Connection for the next query it works for the only next query

Comment: It is advisable to close connections after you're done with them so they are available for other callers who might be trying to access them. However, if you don't do it explicitly, PHP does it on its own. If you're dealing with different servers, and if you keep performance in mind, then you should keep connections open.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the object based method for queries then. It doesn't require changing argument order and this syntax should be repeatable

```
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

You can still use this with the procedural functions

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
```